# Google flabtbuffer How to put array in struct in fbs file

Tags: flatbuffers

This is extension to the following question 
[Size of Serialized data is not reducing using flatbuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966568/size-of-serialized-data-is-not-reducing-using-flatbuffer)

As mentioned in the answer to reduce space we should use Struct. But in my case I need to define an idl file for Polygon

Each polygon will have five or more points, And I will have another DS which will have 
array of polygons 
I have define my fbs file as follow

```
namespace MyFlat;

struct Vertices {
    x : double;
    y  :double;

}
table Polygon  {

    polygons : [Vertices];
}

table Layer {

    polygons : [Polygon];
}


root_type Layer;
```

As expected with this my serialized data size is coming quite large. Is there any way to optimize the padding in table to reduce the serialized buffer size

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to further optimize the structure of your data here, since >90% of the size of these buffers will typically be taken up by `Vertices`.

One thing to consider is to use `float` for `x` and `y`, given that you're unlikely to need to extra resolution.. that would almost half the size of your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. But When I am trying to print the size of 100 polygons having vertices 5 , the size is coming around 10.24KB. Ideally size should be around 8000 bytes(8 KB)

```
b := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(0)
var polyoffset []flatbuffers.UOffsetT
size := 100

StartedAtMarshal := time.Now()
for k := 0; k < size; k++ {
    MyFlat.PolygonStartPolygonsVector(b, 5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        MyFlat.CreateVertices(b, 2.0, 2.4)
    }

    vec := b.EndVector(5)
    MyFlat.PolygonStart(b)
    MyFlat.PolygonAddPolygons(b, vec)
    polyoffset = append(polyoffset, MyFlat.PolygonEnd(b))
}

MyFlat.LayerStartPolygonsVector(b, size)
for _, offset := range polyoffset {
    b.PrependUOffsetT(offset)
}
vec := b.EndVector(size)
MyFlat.LayerStart(b)
MyFlat.LayerAddPolygons(b, vec)
finalOffset := MyFlat.LayerEnd(b)

b.Finish(finalOffset)

EndedAtMarshal := time.Now()
fmt.Println("Elapes Time for Seri", EndedAtMarshal.Sub(StartedAtMarshal).String())
    mybyte := b.FinishedBytes()
    fmt.Println(len(mybyte))
```

Is it expected size or My implementation is wrong